# Swift: How Coordinator pattern show return file path?

Tags: ios

Following this: https://capps.tech/blog/read-files-with-documentpicker-in-swiftui

and this: https://gist.github.com/MentalN/d4d2647aedd761831eeaf1450c299887

After file selection in dialog happend, this method get called:

```swift
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    parent.filePath = urls[0]
    print(urls[0].absoluteString)
}
```

Instead of print filepath, can I pass it to SwiftUI? How?

This methos is inside: `Coordinator` class, and that is inside `DocumentPicker`.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DocumentPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var filePath: URL?
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> DocumentPicker.Coordinator {
        return DocumentPicker.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.item"], in: .open)
        picker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: DocumentPicker.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) {
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        
        var parent: DocumentPicker
        
        init(parent1: DocumentPicker){
            parent = parent1
        }
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            parent.filePath = urls[0]
            print(urls[0].absoluteString)
        }
    }
}
```

In SwiftUI part there is a button in `body`:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
               showDocumentPicker = true
                
            }){ Text("Load JSON schema").padding() }
```

it switch a flag.

```
 @State private var showDocumentPicker = false
```

then sheet get caled:

```
}.sheet(isPresented: self.$showDocumentPicker) {
     DocumentPicker(filePath: $fileContent)
}
```

---

I tried to add `fileContent` to the `body` but got a compiler error:

```swift
Text("\(self.fileContent)").padding()
```

```
No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'
```

Comment: The `@Binding` is getting it already. You can use `onChange` to detect when the `fileContent` has changed.

Comment: Do I need the `onChange` or it is enough to read `fileContent`. Somehow reading `fileContent` raise an error.

Comment: You don’t need it if there is something else listening for the parents body to redraw. It could be as simple as a Text that displays the absolute string. The URL type doesn’t have a string representation. Use something like fileContent.absoluteString